# Cannot create a user in oracle 19c

Tags: oracle

I am unable to create a user in oracle 19c and test the connectivity. Please see the steps that i had followed in the image link.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a connection string that points to the container that you created the user in. If you don’t have an entry in your tnsnames.ora already then create one for your orclpdb PDB (there’ll be a default service with the same name as your container name), then refer to it in your connection command.